# Return zero value if division by zero encountered

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero

I have two lists `a` and `b` of equal length. I want to calculate the sum of their ratio:

```
c = np.sum(a/b)
```

how can I have a zero (0) value in the summation coefficient when there is division by zero?

EDIT: Here a couple of answers I tested for my case, and still raise the error. Probably I am missing something. The aray that contains zero elements is `counts`:

```
try:
    cnterr = (counts/np.mean(counts))*(((cnterr/counts)**2 + (meanerr/np.mean(counts))**2 ))**1/2
except ZeroDivisionError:
    cnterr = (counts/np.mean(counts))*(((meanerr/np.mean(counts))**2 ))**1/2

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
cnterr = (counts/np.mean(counts))*(((cnterr/counts)**2 + (meanerr/np.mean(counts))**2 ))**1/2
```

And also by `np.where()`:

```
cnterr = np.where(counts != 0, ((counts/np.mean(counts))*(((cnterr/counts)**2 + (meanerr/np.mean(counts))**2 ))**1/2), 0)
```

Raise the same error.

Answer (score 3):

To sum values except `divide by 0`,

```
sel = b != 0
c = np.sum(a[sel]/b[sel])
```

The arrays are `float`, you may need to use

```
sel = np.bitwise_not(np.isclose(b, 0))
```

**UPDATE**

If `a` and `b` are not `np.array`, write the follow code in the first.

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

Comment: +1 Best answer so far, with quite a few completely wrong answers, and others not taking benefit from numpy ;-) Looks like the question was not understood.

Comment: Note `a` and `b` need to be converted to numpy arrays first (OP states they are lists)

Comment: For `np.isclose` you can apply broadcasting rules and it will work as expected `np.isclose(b, 0)`.

Comment: Does this return an array with different element numbers than `a` and `b` ?

Comment: the return is `scalar` which is the summation result of `a[i]/b[i]` for all `i` except `b == 0`

Comment: Sure, sorry, my fault (I was thinking to another application of this solution)

Answer (score 2):

```
c = np.where(b != 0, a/b, 0).sum()
```

See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: It's only a warning, but it may be annoying. Actually, numpy's `where`, as any other function, assumes both arguments are computed, unlike Fortran's `where` (a statement, not a function), which would only compute division if `b!=0`.

Answer (score 0):

This works, it puts a `0` in the list where there is a divide by zero:

```
c = np.sum([x/y if y else 0 for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

Or, a variation on @mskimm's answer. Note, you first need to convert your input lists to numpy arrays:

```
a=np.array(a)
b=np.array(b)
c=np.sum(a[b!=0]/b[b!=0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
c = []
for i, j in enumerate(a):
    if b[i] != 0:
        c += [j/b[i]]
    else:
        c += [0]

c = sum(c)
```

Comment: hmm I do have `np` defined, (Python 2.7)

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'`

Comment: If I redefine `a` and `b` as 1D numpy arrays I get a `ValueError`:

Comment: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Yes that's what I did first for the type error, two lists of ints... `a=[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `b=[4, 0, 6, 2]`

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing it out.  I missed something in the question.  My updated answer should work.

Comment: Yep :-)... I think you just need `c=np.sum(c)` at the end

Comment: @John B. The point is to use numpy. Since it has an efficient way to filter arrays, why reinvent the wheel, and a (probably) slower wheel?

Comment: Sorry, I'm somewhat new to python and am not familiar with numpy.  Now I know :D

Answer (score -1):

This is also simple:

```
c = 0 if 0 in b else sum(a/b)
```

Comment: This sets `c` to zero if there is a zero anywhere in `b` - not what the OP wants (unless I've misinterpreted).