# Replacing a division by zero error with a zero in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector D of length N and a matrix A of shape N*M. Vector D has some zero elements. I'm doing this operation:

```
D = D.reshape(-1,1)
A / D
```

However I'm getting a division by zero error because of some elements in D that are zero. What I need is to put zero when there's a division by zero instead of raising an error. How to do this?

E.g. my try:

```
A = [ [0,1,0,0,0,0], 
          [0,0,1,1,0,0],
          [1,0,0,1,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,1,0] 
          ]
A = np.array(A, dtype='float')

D = np.sum(A, axis=1)
D = D.reshape(-1, 1)

A = np.where(D != 0, A / D, 0)

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  A = np.where(D != 0, A / D, 0)
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. You can safely ignore it in this case. As far as I know, your current version is the best solution. See similar discussions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13499499/553404 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23129407/553404

Comment: You can customize how errors are handled using the [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html), however it doesn't provide a way to use a default value when an error is triggered. You can use the `call` mode and then a custom function will be called if an error is raised, however in order for the function to set the default value you'd have to manually pass a reference to the array and somehow tell the function where the error occurred. In other words, it doesn't ease your use-case.

Comment: @AlexTwain did you try the approach proposed in the answer below?

Comment: related [Efficient element-wise matrix division when elements in denominator may be zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041434/efficient-element-wise-matrix-division-when-elements-in-denominator-may-be-zero)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Divide one numpy array by another only where both arrays are non-zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293614/divide-one-numpy-array-by-another-only-where-both-arrays-are-non-zero)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a masked array for `D`, like:

```
D = np.ma.array(D, mask=(D==0))
```

and when you perform the calculations with the masked array only the non-masked values will be considered.

Comment: @moarningsun thank you... you are right! I wrote using `nan_to_num()` because `0/0` was giving `nan`, but I agree with your comment. I've updated the answer with what I think is a more robust approach...

Comment: Oh `0/0` doesn't give `inf` (or `-inf`), I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use try-catch block? Something like

`try:
    some_var = A/D
except ZeroDivisionError:
    some_var = 0`